# How to nest or inherit a template with one json object? using moustache Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, mustache, templating

I have a json object like this

```
let data ={ 
 categories:[{questions:
               [ label:'what is your name',
                 collections:[{name:'abc',id:1}]
               ]
             } 
         ]
  };

let categoryTemplate ='{{#categories}}<div class="box"><div class="box-header"><h3 class="box-title">{{name}}</h3></div><div class="box-body"><div class="row"><div class="col-lg-6"><div class="questionAnswerWrapper"></div></div></div></div></div>{{categories}}'
let categoryTemplateHtml = Mustache.to_html(categoryTemplate,padata);    
$('#categoryTemplateHtml').html(categoryTemplateHtml);

let questionAnswertemplate = {{#questions}}<div class="form-group"><label for="" class="question-label">{{label}}</label><div class="answerWrapper"></div></div>{{/questions}}

let questionAnswertemplateHtml =Mustache.to_html(questionAnswertemplate,padata);
$('.questionAnswerWrapper').append(Mustache.render(questionAnswertemplateHtml));
```

I want to retrieve label of questions from the above json object in one template(consider this as template 1) and in another template(consider this as template 2) I want to use collections and then in a different template(consider this template 3)  I want to inherit template 3 into template 2. With the help of moustache Js

Comment: Hi Ruth. Have you tried anything? If yes, you can post that code here and ask for any issues you faced in your code

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Yes I did Try but I am not getting the result. I have uploaded the rest part of the code.